# slappasswd generating a strange password hash (SHA256 only)

Tags: sha256, openldap

Using slapd 2.5.13+dfsg-1ubuntu1 on ubuntu 22.10:

Password hashes differing between "slappasswd" and "openssl dgst":

```
$ slappasswd -s secret -h '{SHA256}' -o module-path=/usr/lib/ldap -o module-load=pw-sha2 
{SHA256}WIrrpN3OjEVOUf6yrH1j+o+ODuUuNBo979Od4UXnu54=
$ echo -n "secret" | openssl dgst -sha256 -binary | openssl enc -base64
K7gNU3sdo+OL0wNhqoVWhr3g6s1xYv72ol/pe/Unols=
```

But with SHA1:

```
$ slappasswd -s secret -h '{SHA}' -o module-path=/usr/lib/ldap -o module-load=pw-sha2 
{SHA}5en6G6MezRroT3XKqkdPOmY/BfQ=
$ echo -n "secret" | openssl dgst -sha1 -binary | openssl enc -base64
5en6G6MezRroT3XKqkdPOmY/BfQ=
```

we're getting identical hashes.

On an older box (ubuntu 20.04) with slapd 2.4.49+dfsg-2ubuntu1.9 we're seeing:

```
$ slappasswd -s secret -h '{SHA256}' -o module-path=/usr/lib/ldap -o module-load=pw-sha2
{SHA256}K7gNU3sdo+OL0wNhqoVWhr3g6s1xYv72ol/pe/Unols=
$ echo -n "secret" | openssl dgst -sha256 -binary | openssl enc -base64
K7gNU3sdo+OL0wNhqoVWhr3g6s1xYv72ol/pe/Unols=
```

So why is the SHA256 password hash generated by the  2.5.13 slappasswd command different from the hashes generated by the other programs/versions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously we hitted with that error above a gcc-Compiler/Optimizer-Bug. The gcc-Version used on Ubuntu kinetic is 12.2.0.

We bisected the problem to the gcc-Optimizer (without any `-O` the error is gone). Finally: when the sha2-contrib-Module is (re-)built with the flag `-fno-strict-aliasing` the error goes away. This does not fix the gcc-Problem, but our ssha256-error with that particular module.

Diff:

```
--- a/contrib/slapd-modules/passwd/sha2/Makefile
+++ b/contrib/slapd-modules/passwd/sha2/Makefile
@@ -9,7 +9,7 @@
 LIBTOOL = $(LDAP_BUILD)/libtool
 INSTALL = /usr/bin/install
 CC = gcc
-OPT = -g -O2
+OPT = -g -O2 -fno-strict-aliasing
 DEFS =
 #DEFS = -DSLAPD_SHA2_DEBUG
 INCS = $(LDAP_INC)
```